# Action on Lard Oil

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

If water is mixed with lard oil and heated (creating some *super-critical* liquid with water), how does this affect the volatility of the mixture in comparison with its *purity*..?

So, My question is: What happens when a mixture of lard oil and water is compressed and then heated to over some $\approx800^o\text{C}$ almost instantaneously?

**Note:** I'm no physicist or chemist, so simplicity would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you making a car that runs on pigs?

Comment: Nice suite to [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) I think so...

Comment: Water boils at 100 C, lard at around 50 C, so I can't imagine it lasting too long before a flash evaporation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyone who has done the experiment, but I'd guess that under those conditions the lard will rapidly hydolyse and you'd be left with a solution of glycerol and saturated fatty acids in water. Actually at 800C the fatty acids will probably degrade and polymerise and you'd be left with poorly characterised brown gunk.

Are you trying to make biodiesel from the lard? If so you need much lower temperatures - probably around 200C rather than 800C.

Comment: +1: Just like everytime. For now, I should add "Revival of the Chemist". But, I've got a question :- Isn't this better suite to chemistry rather than physics..? 'cause it's a bit BORING...

Comment: Yes, I'd guess it's better on the chemistry SE.